# Subtract specific indexed values from lists of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list like

```
l1 = [[403, 105], [403, 100], [403, 92], [403, 95], [403, 89]].
```

I want to subtract 403 from all the 403s and check if the difference is 0.

I again want to check the difference of 105 from 100, 92, 95 and 89 respectively and check the
difference.
The result I want to obtain is:

```
diffelement1 = [0,0,0,0]
diffelement2 = [5,13,10,16]
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `zip` unpacking:

```
diffelement1, diffelement2 = zip(*((abs(403 - x), abs(105 - y)) for x, y in l1[1:]))
```

---

```
>>> diffelement1
(0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> diffelement2
(5, 13, 10, 16)
>>>
```

If you want to get the first value dynamically, do:

```
diffelements = list(zip(*((abs(l1[0][i] - v) for i, v in enumerate(lst)) for lst in l1[1:])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but the lists of list can have varying elements and that's not constant. Therefore, the diffelementx also changes accordingly. Is there anyway to make it dynamic?

Comment: @Chougo Check my second solution.

Comment: Yeah your second solution work but I have to manually change the code, let's say my list is now:
l1 = [[403, 105,100], [403, 100,100], [403, 92,100], [403, 95,100], [403, 89,100]]
Then my code is:
diffelement1, diffelement2, diffelement3 = zip(*((abs(l1[0][0] - x), abs(l1[0][1] - y), abs(l1[0][2] - z)) for x, y,z in l1[1:]))
But here I am hardcoding the values of l1[0][0] l1[0][1]... also I have to key in another variable z to my loop. My question is more on automating this entire solution and the code will be able to pickup the number of variables in the loop as well.

Comment: @Chougo Edited my answer, check the bottom code, please feel free to mark and upvote if you like :)

Comment: Sure and thanks but it looks like giving an error:
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'generator'

Comment: @Chougo Edited my answer, now its working fine as tested

Comment: @U-12-Forward. Thanks for the code this works now. For my case casted it to a list.